# AWS Kinesis Firehose is not inserting data in Redshift

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I know this question has been asked several times in Stack Overflow, but none of the answers I read is able to solve what I'm experiencing.

I have a Boto3 script to copy a MySQL table to Kinesis Streams. Then at the other end, there's a KCL Node JS script to read the stream from Kinesis Streams and write to S3. So far so good.

I set up Kinesis Firehose, Redshift and S3 in the same region. I then set up Firehose to read from S3 and write to Redshift. When tested with demo data provided at Firehose, all good.

I then setup a Redshift table which has all the columns from the MySQL table. Some data types are not supported by Redshift and thus I used a different data type but I was confident that Firehose would be able to write to the Redshift table without problem.

Below is the MySQL table screenshot.

[image: MySQL table]

And below is the Redshift table screenshot.

[image: Redshift table]

As you can see, the data types are not all the same. I wonder if Redshift is so sensitive to the level that every data type must be the same as the MySQL table.

By the way, I did specify **JSON 'auto'** in the Firehost COPY command and enabled logging. Unfortunately there's no error logged.

Comment: So, you are getting the files in S3 but not in redshift?

Comment: Yes. As explained in my question detail, I managed to get the files into S3 using a Node JS KCL script.

Comment: Once the file is in S3, try COPY command manually to see if you can get the data into redshift for few files.

Comment: If you dont see any errors in stl_load_errors table, that means your copy was not actually initiated. Firehose error logging does not help much, I know

Comment: Yes there's nothing in **stl_load_errors** table, so what can I do about it?

Comment: Use COPY command manually, to see if you get any errors.

Comment: Where can I run the COPY command manually?

Comment: @KelvinLowEeHahn Install SQLWorkbench http://www.sql-workbench.net/downloads.html, and then follow the instructions here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-using-workbench.html to run COPY command manually

Comment: I found out that the JSON produced is not flat format and contains other info which when parsed to Redshift will result in NULL rows. I followed this tutorial in producing the JSON. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/streaming-changes-in-a-database-with-amazon-kinesis/

Any idea how can I strip off those unneeded info by editing the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a myriad of reasons of why you don't see records in Redshift. After Firehose puts the records in S3, a COPY command is performed from Redshift to get the files from S3 and into the cluster.

If you are not seeing STL_LOAD_ERRORS, then Firehose can't connect to Redshift. You can verify this in the Firehose console, you'll find more information under the Redshift Logs tab.

Also, make sure that you've allowed incoming connections from Firehose's IP range in the region under your VPC for Redshift.